# manifest is not allowed for android

Tags: java, android, manifest

I have just imported some projects,
but manifest and resources files are showing errors.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.techown.mission01">

    <application
        android:allowBachup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DoItMission01">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the problem message is below

```
Attribute android:allowBackup is not allowed here
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
```

I have tried..

close and reopen manifest.xml file.
rebuild project.
modify code on notepad and then put it in manifest.xml file.
confirmed that both files are at right place in hierarchy.
invalidate cashes and restart.

Comment: `allowBachup` is misspelled.

Comment: After correcting misspelled "allowBackup" as suggested by @Michael, if you still facing the issue then try once by adding manifest node:
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"